# Infinitesimal generator of time-dependent Markov diffusion

Tags: stochastic-processes

If one talks about homogeneous Markov diffusion
$$
\mathrm dX_t = \mu(X_t)\mathrm dt+\sigma(X_t)\mathrm dw_t
$$
with $\mu,\sigma$ sufficiently differentiable and of appropriate dimensions, there is nice equation for a function $m_f(x,t) = \mathsf E_x f(X_t)$ for $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial m_f}{\partial t} &= \mu\frac{\partial m_f}{\partial x}+\frac12\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 m_f}{\partial x^2},
\\
m(x,0)&=f(x).
\end{cases}
$$

On the other hand, while answering on the question [Stochastic model](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1452/stochastic-model/1453#1453) I advised to use Fokker-Plank equation for the density of the process rather then the very same equation for $m_f$.

The problem I had is the following. Since $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are time-dependent there, one can construct a process $Z_t = (X_t,Y_t)$ with $\mathrm dY_t = \mathrm dt$ and obtain everything for this process just using theory of homogeneous/time-independent Markov processes (how it is usually written in the books). Unfortunately, if you derive an infinitesimal generator for this process then you obtain
$$
\mathcal A_Zg(x,y) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}+\mu\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+\frac12\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}.
$$

For sure, now one shoud define $m_f(\tau|x,t) = \mathsf E_{x,t}f(X_{t+\tau})$ where $\tau\in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$. If I am not wrong then it follows
$$
\frac{\partial m_f}{\partial \tau} = \frac{\partial m_f}{\partial t}+\mu\frac{\partial m_f}{\partial x}+\frac12\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 m_f}{\partial x^2}\quad(*)
$$
which is kind of strange equation.

My question has three parts:

1. is an equation $(*)$ correct? if yes, are there developed methods for its solutions?
2. if this equation is not correct, what is the right equation?
3. I usually have problems when deal with non-homogeneous Markov processes since trick $Z_t = (t,X_t)$ does not help me. Could you refer me to literature where authors consider non-homogeneous Markov processes in details (rather then saying that this trick will help to use provided theory of homogeneous processes)?

Comment: Also asked it here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/70447/time-dependent-markov-process-infinitesimal-generator